# Password Protect a Directory with .htaccess when a Rewrite rule is preventing it from working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, passwords

So I'd like to password protect my directory `/admin/` so I put a `.htaccess` in the `/admin/` folder with all the proper info to find the `htpasswd` file.

The only problem is that when I try to navigate to a file in that directory, it loads and loads and never prompts me for a password, and eventually just times out.

I think this is due to the fact that I have a rewrite condition in my `public_html` `.htaccess` file. It's set up so that any time someone goes to `mydomain.com/theirusername` it will redirect to `mydomain.com/profile/user.php?username=theirusername`.

Is there any way to override this so this specific directory will prompt me for my password?

Here is the current code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ profile/user.php?name=$0
```

This is the .htaccess in the /admin folder:

```
AuthUserFile "/home/passwords/passwd"
AuthName "Please Log In"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about: rewrite condition in your `public_html` `.htaccess` file.

Do the following:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/?
RewriteRule .+ profile/user.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @jonjammamsm There is definitely no problem with the RewriteRule. Just saw your [bad flag delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146007/rewritecond-bad-flag-delimiter-htaccess-failing-) remove unnecessary spaces! & RewriteRule .+ profile/user.php?name=$0 is RewriteRule .+ profile/user.php?name=$1 $0 is not used.to-password-protect-my-direc

Comment: Ahhhh, finally! I'm glad you saw that other post, because I finally found the error log. And thank you so much for discovering that $0 instead of $1. That fixed it! .htaccess is such a pain in the ass. I wish I knew more about it so I could fix problems like this, but every time I work with it I run into huge brick walls like this and it just pisses me off. Anyway, thank you so much!